# Dos condiciones en PHP y una ventana emergente (modal)

Tags: php, html

Mi sitio web es para consultar las calificaciones de cada alumno, pero en el login necesito implementar dos condiciones, la primera es que si el parámetro `Pago` es igual a `Atrasado`, entonces lance una venta emergente que diga que no se puede acceder a las calificaciones ya que no va al corriente con los pagos, la segunda es que si la matricula es igual a `00000001` entonces en lugar de dirigirlo a la página de calificaciones, lo mande a un *CRUD* (este ya lo tengo) ya que este usuario es el admin.

Básicamente lo que necesito es saber en que parte colocar las condiciones para que funcionen, y como implementar la ventana emergente (esta si que no se hacerla).

Aquí dejo mi código:

```
<?php
session_start();
include('Conexion.php');
if (isset($_POST['Matricula']) && isset($_POST['Contraseña']) ) {

function validate($data){
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}

$Matricula = validate($_POST['Matricula']); 
$Contraseña = validate($_POST['Contraseña']);
$Pago = validate($_POST['EstatusPago']);

if (empty($Matricula)) {
    header("Location: Index.php?error=La Matricula es Requerida");
    exit();
}elseif (empty($Contraseña)) {
    header("Location: Index.php?error=La Contraseña Es Requerida");
    exit();
}else{

    // $Contraseña = md5($Contraseña);

    $Sql = "SELECT * FROM alumnos WHERE Matricula = '$Matricula' AND Contraseña='$Contraseña'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $Sql);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) === 1) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        if ($row['Matricula'] === $Matricula && $row['Contraseña'] === $Contraseña) {
            $_SESSION['Matricula'] = $row['Matricula'];
            $_SESSION['Nombre'] = $row['Nombre'];
            $_SESSION['Id'] = $row['Id'];
            header("Location: Inicio.php");
            exit();
        }else {
            header("Location: Index.php?error=La Matricula o la Contraseña son incorrectas");
            exit();
        }

    }else {
        header("Location: Index.php?error=La Matricula o la Contraseña son incorrectas");
        exit();
    }
}

} else {
header("Location: Index.php");
        exit();
}
```

Comment: empezando porque algo simple en programacion jamas se usa la `ñ` como nombre de variable.. segundo donde estan definidas estas definido `atraso` que menciones o cual es la estructura de tu tabla?

Comment: Pues hasta ahorita no he tenido ningún problema con las ñ
En cuanto a la tabla, es nombrada Alumnos y los campos son  Matricula (clave principal), Nombre, Curp, Generacion, Grupo, Estatus de Pago (en este caso "atrasado" se refiere a que si el alumno va atrasado en el pago, no puede loguearse para consultar sus calificaciones) y Contraseña.

Comment: Hola. Aunque hasta ahora la `ñ` no te haya dado problemas, podría darlos en un futuro, por ejemplo en un entorno donde hayas olvidado configurar adecuadamente la codificación. Eso podría provocar errores graves, en el mismo código o en los datos, por tanto, no consideres sin importancia el señalamiento que te hace @Bryro. Por otra parte, dinos qué es lo que hace tu código actualmente. Yo intenté analizarlo, pero al ver que seguido de un `if` declaras una función, ahí me quedé. ¿Eso no da un error grave? Aunque no lo diera, declarar una función dentro de un `if` no es práctica habitual en PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero comentarte que tu código se ve bastante antiguo. Algunas cosas como la validación de datos entrantes que haces no es muy segura, usar para contraseñas md5 tampoco está ya muy aconsejado, etc. También te aconsejo encarecidamente que no uses la ñ, es un error bastante importante.

Entrando en tu duda.
Entiendo que $pago se envía como parte del formulario lo cual no tiene mucho sentido, lo normal sería tenerlo en una tabla y no usar un string sino un int o un boleano
Si realmente el pago va en el post del form, yo pondría el primer if para mirar el pago al principio del todo para evitar la consulta.
En cuanto a si es el usuario 1, pues el if lo pondría antes del header("Location: Inicio.php");

respecto al modal, yo usaría bootstrap y lanzara el modal https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/modal/.
También tienes la posibilidad de usar un poco de javascript ( me parece mejor solución en este caso) y usar algo como https://sweetalert2.github.io/